# Avoid QML error: "This is probably intended to be a signal handler but no signal of the target matches the name."

Tags: qt, qml

I have working QML that has an `ApplicationWindow` with a `Loader`.  The loader has a default qml file `GameStart.qml` representing a screen with some startup activities.  For simplicity, say the 1st screen can navigate to the 2nd screen `gamePlay.qml` and the 2nd can navigate back to the 1st.  The navigation is done by the loaded item emitting a signal that the `ApplicationWindow` has slots for.  All that happens in the slots is the `Loader`'s source gets modified.

```
// RootWindow.qml
import QtQuick          2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Window   2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts  1.12
ApplicationWindow {
    id:             mainWindow
    minimumWidth:   Math.min(215 * Screen.pixelDensity, Screen.width)
    minimumHeight:  Math.min(120 * Screen.pixelDensity, Screen.height)
    visible:        true
    color:          "turquoise"

    property string currentScreen: "GameStart.qml"

    Loader {
        id:             dynamicLoader
        anchors.fill:   parent
        source:         currentScreen
    }

    Connections {
        target: dynamicLoader.item
        function onPlayGame() {
            currentScreen = "GamePlay.qml"
            console.log("currentScreen: ", currentScreen)
        }
    }
    Connections {
        target: dynamicLoader.item
        function onEndGame() {
            currentScreen = "GameStart.qml"
            console.log("currentScreen: ", currentScreen)
        }
    }
}
```

The default screen and the other screen declare signals like this:

```
// GameStart.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Item {
    id: gameStart
    anchors.top: parent.top
    height: parent.height
    width: parent.width
    signal playGame

    RowLayout {
        id: layout
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        RoundButton {
            id: playButton
            text: "Play"
            width: 40
            radius: 2
            font.pointSize: 12
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
            onClicked: {
                gameStart.playGame()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Things work the way I expect them to, but there is a runtime error message that pops up that I'd rather not have:

```
qrc:/qml/RootWindow.qml:25:5: QML Connections: Detected function "onPlayGame" in Connections element. This is probably intended to be a signal handler but no signal of the target matches the name.
```

My guess is this happens because I use as the `Connections` target: *dynamicLoader.item* and that is not a specific object id, but rather a dynamically loaded object.  I am not able to use e.g. `gameStart` or `gamePlay` as targets of the `Connections` in `RootWindow.qml`, however.  Those IDs are not recognized within that file.

I suspect I have not discovered the idiomatic way of doing this and my way is kludgey.  What should I do to avoid this runtime message?

EDIT: here's the GamePlay.qml file and also PlayerArea.qml

```
// GamePlay.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12
import QtQml.Models 2.12
import QtQml 2.12


Item {
    id: gamePlay
    signal endGame
    property var playerArray : game.getPlayers()

    ListModel {
        id: playerLayoutModel
        ListElement {
            property var row: 1
            property var column: 0
        }
        ListElement {
            property var row: 1
            property var column: 2
        }
        ListElement {
            property var row: 0
            property var column: 1
        }
        ListElement {
            property var row: 2
            property var column: 1
        }
    }

    ColumnLayout {
        id: mainColumn
        spacing: 2
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        Rectangle {
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
            height: 100
            width: 250
            color: "turquoise"
            RowLayout {
                id: gameButtonsLayout
                anchors.fill: parent
                Button {
                    id: deal
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 50
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 80
                    text: "Deal"
                }

                Button {
                    id: end
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 50
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 80
                    text: "End Game"
                    onClicked: {
                        gamePlay.endGame()
                    }
                }

                Button {
                    id: save
                    Layout.preferredHeight: 50
                    Layout.preferredWidth: 80
                    text: "Save Game"
                }
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            anchors.horizontalCenter: Layout.horizontalCenter
            color: "turquoise"

            GridLayout {
                id: gridnew
                columns: 3
                rows: 3
                anchors.fill: parent
                property var playerCnt: playerArray.length

                Repeater {
                    model: playerLayoutModel
                    delegate: playerArea
                }

                Component {
                    id: playerArea
                    PlayerArea {
                        color: "red"
                        playerName: playerArray[index]
                        Layout.row: model.row
                        Layout.column: model.column
                        Layout.fillHeight: true
                        Layout.fillWidth: true
                        enabled: gridnew.playerCnt > index ? true : false
                        opacity: gridnew.playerCnt > index ? true : false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// PlayerArea.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Item {
    id: playerArea
    property string playerName
    property string cardText
    property string color

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        Label {
            color: playerArea.color
            height: 50
            width: 50
            text: cardText
        }
        //        }


        Label {
            id: nameLabel
            height: 50
            width: 50
            text: playerName
        }

        Button {
            id: playButton
            height: 50
            width: 50
            text: "Play Card"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please remove or comment `}` before `gameStart.playGame()`

Comment: Where you have defined the signal `endGame`, if I remove the connection associated with that signal and correct the TYPO that I indicated in my previous comment then I do not reproduce the problem. Also change to `signal playGame()`

Comment: Also add the imports

Comment: what is  `PlayerArea`? Please enter the code for your custom items or replace them with standard items. It is difficult to test your code if you do not provide a copy-paste code. At the beginning I had to look for the imports which was an unnecessary and tedious task

Comment: I will only use the MRE code, I will not use external links. Please read [ask]

Comment: I increased the scope of this question at the request of @eyllanesc. The question is probably simpler than he thinks and it all centers on the "target: dynamicLoader.item".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Jeremy_k on the Qt forums for this suggestion.  He pointed out something I missed in the online documentation for the Connections type.

> ignoreUnknownSignals : bool
>
> Normally, a connection to a non-existent signal produces runtime
> errors.
>
> If this property is set to true, such errors are ignored. This is
> useful if you intend to connect to different types of objects,
> handling a different set of signals for each object.

The runtime message goes away when I set that property to true e.g.

```
    Connections {
        target: dynamicLoader.item
        ignoreUnknownSignals: true
        function onPlayGame() {
            currentScreen = "GamePlay.qml"
            console.log("currentScreen: ", currentScreen)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at a given moment the item that handles the Loader does not have both signals so one of the connections will complain. One possible solution is to make the connections after the item is loaded:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow

    property string currentScreen: "GameStart.qml"

    function handlePlayGame() {
        currentScreen = "GamePlay.qml";
    }

    function handleEndGame() {
        currentScreen = "GameStart.qml";
    }

    minimumWidth: Math.min(215 * Screen.pixelDensity, Screen.width)
    minimumHeight: Math.min(120 * Screen.pixelDensity, Screen.height)
    visible: true
    color: "turquoise"

    Loader {
        id: dynamicLoader

        anchors.fill: parent
        source: currentScreen
        onLoaded: function() {
            switch (dynamicLoader.source.toString()) {
            case Qt.resolvedUrl("GameStart.qml"):
                dynamicLoader.item.playGame.connect(handlePlayGame);
                break;
            case Qt.resolvedUrl("GamePlay.qml"):
                dynamicLoader.item.endGame.connect(handleEndGame);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

On the other hand, when a signal is declared, parentheses must be used, so you must change to:

```
signal playGame()
```

```
signal endGame()
```